# Filter Centos 6 only with Ansible setup and filter | not using ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am trying to list out all Centos 6 servers and want to prepare its OS up-gradation.

For a single command, I use:

```
# ansible myhost -b -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_distribution_major_version'
```

As you know, it simply lists out all Centos 6, 7, 8, but I want only Centos 6 servers. How to filter that in a single command for handy instead of a YAML file and running it using ansible-playbook.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way that you can adapt for other type of info.

1. Turn on fact caching so that you can gather facts once and reuse (in playbooks or ad-hoc commands). Here is a minimal `ansible.cfg` file to store the cache info in json files on disk. See [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html) for other available plugin

   ```
   [defaults]
   fact_caching=jsonfile
   fact_caching_connection=/tmp/ansibleFactCache
   ```

   Store that file in the current directory from where you will issue your ad-hoc and playbook commands
2. Populate the fact cache for all your host:

   ```sh
   ansible all -i your/inventory.yml -m setup
   ```
3. You can now issue a debug ad-hoc task targeting localhost, using the same inventory and selecting only the host names matching some criteria. Example for `CentOS 6` like in your question:

   ```
   $ ansible localhost -i your/inventory.yml -m debug -a msg="{{ hostvars | dict2items | map(attribute='value') | selectattr('ansible_distribution', 'eq', 'CentOS') | selectattr('ansible_distribution_major_version', 'eq', '6') | map(attribute='inventory_hostname') }}"
   localhost | SUCCESS => {
       "msg": [
           "host_a",
           "host_d"
       ]
   }
   ```